# How does it takes to deadlift a sports car?

Tags: everyday-life, power, biophysics

In the movie Furious 7, Dom lift a Lykan HyperSport with bare hands.

Given that in reality, how strong it has to be to lift a Lykan HyperSport(1,380 kg), says to 40 cm in one rear end, and hold it for 10 seconds?

How much is one-rep max of this guy's deadlifting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many examples of "normal" people in a crisis situation lifting a car to help rescue a person trapped under a vehicle.  Have a look at this Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysterical_strength

Comment: Easy: just take the integral of mass over the length of the car and apply the laws of torque.